# Very strange deadlock

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, database-deadlocks

i have a deadlock:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process296f390">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process296f390" taskpriority="0" logused="6540" waitresource="OBJECT: 10:1797581442:0 " waittime="7542" ownerId="1123440" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.650" XDES="0x211bdb30" lockMode="IS" schedulerid="2" kpid="3920" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.960" lastbatchcompleted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.960" lastattention="2016-01-13T13:26:34.623" clientapp="Ciel V7" hostname="GEORGEL" hostpid="10516" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1123440" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000004dda5901ca432e225cfc8d822e286c487bd004ce">
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed], 
    [Extent1].[WarehouseId] AS [WarehouseId], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[DischargeMethodId] AS [DischargeMethodId], 
    [Extent1].[RunDischargePerDocument] AS [RunDischargePerDocument]
    FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IsClosed] = 1)
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EndDate] DESC     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed], 
    [Extent1].[WarehouseId] AS [WarehouseId], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[DischargeMethodId] AS [DischargeMethodId], 
    [Extent1].[RunDischargePerDocument] AS [RunDischargePerDocument]
    FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IsClosed] = 1)
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EndDate] DESC    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process296f558" taskpriority="0" logused="15780" waitresource="KEY: 10:72057594054377472 (e600db96a62a)" waittime="7482" ownerId="1123280" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.447" XDES="0x155c39f8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="5316" status="suspended" spid="73" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:59.023" lastbatchcompleted="2016-01-13T13:26:59.007" clientapp="Ciel V7" hostname="TEST" hostpid="1812" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1123280" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="140" sqlhandle="0x02000000348bd118f2d3eef1c2e464e6f2a2e3c731e41862">
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[Series] AS [Series], 
    [Project1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ValidationId] AS [ValidationId], 
        [Extent1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[Series] AS [Series]
        FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((DATEDIFF(day, [Extent1].[Date], @p__linq__0)) &lt;= 0) AND ([Extent1].[LookupTypeId] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[LookupStatusId] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] = @p__linq__3) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 0)))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] DESC, [Project1].[ValidationId] DESC     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p__linq__0 datetime,@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 int,@p__linq__3 int)SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[Series] AS [Series], 
    [Project1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ValidationId] AS [ValidationId], 
        [Extent1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[Series] AS [Series]
        FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((DATEDIFF(day, [Extent1].[Date], @p__linq__0)) &lt;= 0) AND ([Extent1].[LookupTypeId] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[LookupStatusId] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] = @p__linq__3) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 0)))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] DESC, [Project1].[ValidationId] DESC    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1797581442" subresource="FULL" dbid="10" objectname="CielStd_a1.dbo.Periods" id="lock30da0c80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1797581442">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process296f558" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process296f390" mode="IS" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594054377472" dbid="10" objectname="CielStd_a1.dbo.Documents" indexname="PK_Document" id="lock25c94700" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594054377472">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process296f390" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process296f558" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Table deffinitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Periods](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsClosed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseId] [int] NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [DischargeMethodId] [int] NULL,
    [RunDischargePerDocument] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Periods] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Periods] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Periods_IsClosed]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsClosed]
GO
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ValidationId] [int] NULL,
    [PartnerId] [int] NULL,
    [LookupStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LookupTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AppSeriesValueId] [int] NULL,
    [AgentId] [int] NULL,
    [BankAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [Vat] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [VatLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [NrDoc] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DueDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NetTotalAmount] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [NetTotalAmountLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [Series] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [WareHouseId] [int] NULL,
    [DestinationWareHouseId] [int] NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BadDocument] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [int] NULL,
    [ExchangeRate] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [ReverseCharge] [bit] NULL,
    [Transport] [bit] NULL,
    [Total] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [KindOfTransport] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TakenBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TakenAt] [datetime] NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalPhysiscalStockValue] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalCalculatedStockValue] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TreasuryDocumentTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [RemainingValue] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [RemainingValueLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [NIRSeries] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ImportedDocumentsSeries] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ImportedByDocumentsSeries] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TreasuryHouseId] [int] NULL,
    [RelatedDocumentTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [InitialRemainingValue] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalInWords] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AccountId] [int] NULL,
    [TreasuryDocumentAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [TotalPaymentWithCard] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalPaymentWithTickets] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalIn] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalOut] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalInLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [TotalOutLocalCurrency] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [AccountingNoteAutoNumber] [int] NULL,
    [BillingRepresentativeId] [int] NULL,
    [DelegateId] [int] NULL,
    [PartnerDeliveryAddressId] [int] NULL,
    [HasStockDifferences] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsVATCollectableOnPayment] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsStorno] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsInitialBalance] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [SourceTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [IsLinkedToDistribution] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WorksiteId] [int] NULL,
    [TransportAccountingNoteLookupTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [PartnerWorksiteId] [int] NULL,
    [DocumentSeriesConfigurationId] [int] NULL,
    [HasImo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasInventoryItem] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BaseExchangeRate] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [AdjustmentPercentExchangeRate] [decimal](28, 6) NULL,
    [IdLookupDocumentFlowType] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_AccountingPlans] FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AccountingPlans] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_AccountingPlans]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Addresses_PartnerDeliveryAddressId] FOREIGN KEY([PartnerDeliveryAddressId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Addresses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Addresses_PartnerDeliveryAddressId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Agents] FOREIGN KEY([AgentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Agents] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Agents]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_BankAccounts] FOREIGN KEY([BankAccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BankAccounts] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_BankAccounts]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_BillingRepresentatives] FOREIGN KEY([BillingRepresentativeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BillingRepresentatives] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_BillingRepresentatives]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_ContactPersons] FOREIGN KEY([DelegateId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ContactPersons] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_ContactPersons]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Currencies] FOREIGN KEY([CurrencyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Currencies] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Currencies]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocumentSeriesConfiguration] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentSeriesConfigurationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DocumentSeriesConfiguration] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocumentSeriesConfiguration]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocumentSeriesValues] FOREIGN KEY([AppSeriesValueId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DocumentSeriesValues] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocumentSeriesValues]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Employees]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_LookupDocumentFlowType] FOREIGN KEY([IdLookupDocumentFlowType])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Lookup] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_LookupDocumentFlowType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Partners] FOREIGN KEY([PartnerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Partners] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Partners]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_PartnerWorksites] FOREIGN KEY([PartnerWorksiteId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PartnerAddresses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_PartnerWorksites]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_TreasuryDocumentTypes] FOREIGN KEY([TreasuryDocumentTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TreasuryDocumentTypes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_TreasuryDocumentTypes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_TreasuryHouses] FOREIGN KEY([TreasuryHouseId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TreasuryHouses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_TreasuryHouses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Warehouses] FOREIGN KEY([WareHouseId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Warehouses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Warehouses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Warehouses1] FOREIGN KEY([DestinationWareHouseId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Warehouses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Warehouses1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Worksites] FOREIGN KEY([WorksiteId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Worksites] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Worksites]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_HasStockDifferences]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [HasStockDifferences]
GO
```

I've spent all my day in searching for a reason of this deadlock occurence but nothing!. Help please.

Another deadlock involving same tables:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process2d15caa8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process2d15caa8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 10:1797581442:0 " waittime="2585" ownerId="1123615" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.867" XDES="0x20162280" lockMode="IS" schedulerid="1" kpid="3788" status="suspended" spid="76" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.913" lastbatchcompleted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.900" clientapp="Ciel V7" hostname="PAULP" hostpid="11944" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1123615" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="66" sqlhandle="0x020000005707df11bae6fb9a7a8dd71635ee331c03da99d9">
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed]
        FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[StartDate] &lt;= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[EndDate] &gt;= @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Limit1]     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int)SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed]
        FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[StartDate] &lt;= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[EndDate] &gt;= @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Limit1]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process296f390" taskpriority="0" logused="6540" waitresource="OBJECT: 10:1797581442:0 " waittime="2542" ownerId="1123440" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.650" XDES="0x211bdb30" lockMode="IS" schedulerid="2" kpid="3920" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.960" lastbatchcompleted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.960" lastattention="2016-01-13T13:26:34.623" clientapp="Ciel V7" hostname="GEORGEL" hostpid="10516" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1123440" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000004dda5901ca432e225cfc8d822e286c487bd004ce">
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed], 
    [Extent1].[WarehouseId] AS [WarehouseId], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[DischargeMethodId] AS [DischargeMethodId], 
    [Extent1].[RunDischargePerDocument] AS [RunDischargePerDocument]
    FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IsClosed] = 1)
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EndDate] DESC     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsClosed] AS [IsClosed], 
    [Extent1].[WarehouseId] AS [WarehouseId], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[DischargeMethodId] AS [DischargeMethodId], 
    [Extent1].[RunDischargePerDocument] AS [RunDischargePerDocument]
    FROM [dbo].[Periods] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IsClosed] = 1)
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EndDate] DESC    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process296f558" taskpriority="0" logused="15780" waitresource="KEY: 10:72057594054377472 (e600db96a62a)" waittime="2481" ownerId="1123280" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:58.447" XDES="0x155c39f8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="5316" status="suspended" spid="73" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-01-13T13:26:59.023" lastbatchcompleted="2016-01-13T13:26:59.007" clientapp="Ciel V7" hostname="TEST" hostpid="1812" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1123280" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="140" sqlhandle="0x02000000348bd118f2d3eef1c2e464e6f2a2e3c731e41862">
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[Series] AS [Series], 
    [Project1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ValidationId] AS [ValidationId], 
        [Extent1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[Series] AS [Series]
        FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((DATEDIFF(day, [Extent1].[Date], @p__linq__0)) &lt;= 0) AND ([Extent1].[LookupTypeId] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[LookupStatusId] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] = @p__linq__3) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 0)))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] DESC, [Project1].[ValidationId] DESC     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p__linq__0 datetime,@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 int,@p__linq__3 int)SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[Series] AS [Series], 
    [Project1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ValidationId] AS [ValidationId], 
        [Extent1].[NrDoc] AS [NrDoc], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[Series] AS [Series]
        FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((DATEDIFF(day, [Extent1].[Date], @p__linq__0)) &lt;= 0) AND ([Extent1].[LookupTypeId] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[LookupStatusId] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] = @p__linq__3) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SourceTypeId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 0)))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] DESC, [Project1].[ValidationId] DESC    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1797581442" subresource="FULL" dbid="10" objectname="CielStd_a1.dbo.Periods" id="lock30da0c80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1797581442">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process296f558" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process2d15caa8" mode="IS" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1797581442" subresource="FULL" dbid="10" objectname="CielStd_a1.dbo.Periods" id="lock30da0c80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1797581442">
    <owner-list/>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process296f390" mode="IS" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594054377472" dbid="10" objectname="CielStd_a1.dbo.Documents" indexname="PK_Document" id="lock25c94700" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594054377472">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process296f390" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process296f558" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

After some investigations, I found that on our transactions we perform a query similar to this: 
SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WITH (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX)

The table "Sometable" does not have anything to do with given tables above. Looks like TABLOCKX hint blocks somehow other database objects. Can anyone give me a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Wild guess. Your ORM by default use `SERIALIZABLE` transaction level. Very easy to check with `sp_whoisactive @get_additional_info=1` Something like **[here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XHXpF.png)**.

Comment: Not the case, i am in read committed isolation level.

Comment: Looks like Entity Framework to me... amirite?

Comment: exactly in that moment? I could try but I have to re-create the deadlock ... it does not occur every time

Comment: I've added another deadlock that occured just a few seconds before the first one!!!

Comment: From both graphs you can read that isolation level is read committed ( isolationlevel="read committed (2)" ).